# How do I get the URI of my SQLite database in my Android app?

Tags: android, database, uri

I have an Android app with a database called "myTestDB" with a table called "list_items".  I want to use the Cursor getContentResolver().query() method to get a cursor to add to a SimpleCursorAdapter.  The first argument of the query() method is a URI and I'm not sure what the URI should look like.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it is fairly straightforward Method call looks like this

`mDataBase.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);`

where, TABLE_NAME = your SQLite table name and columns is a string array like

`String columns[] = new String[] { "Column1" };`

If you want all columns, you can pass `null` for second argument.

Correction: **As mentioned by a few others, there is no URI.**

Comment: Please, fix your answer. There is no `URI` for this case. See what CommonsWare and EboMike said.

Comment: Thank you. I see now the answer is downvoted, however to be clear - this is not from me.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question.

Answer (score 4):

You do not use `getContentResolver()` to access a SQLite database directly. You use `getContentResolver()` when working with content providers. You call `query()` on a `SQLiteDatabase` object to get a `Cursor` for use with `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Comment: Why does `CursorLoader` have a `Uri` then?

Comment: @mattblang: This question and answer are from 2010. The `Loader` framework did not exist in 2010. Also, `CursorLoader` does not directly access a `SQLiteDatabase` either, but rather does what my answer describes: uses a `ContentResolver` to query a `ContentProvider` via that `Uri`.

Answer (score 1):

A database doesn't have a Uri (other than the file where it's located). Data managed through a content provider has one. If you want to use the content resolver to perform a query, you need to write a content provider first.

If you don't want to do that, simply use SQLiteDatabase's `query` function - it returns a Cursor that you can pass to the SimpleCursorAdapter.